# How to calculate YOY, QOQ, MOM, WOW, DOD using window function for day dimension

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to transform the self joins of this query into windowing analytical functions to calculate Amount:

- DOD - day over day
- WOW - week over week
- MOM - month over month
- QOQ - quarter over quarter
- YOY - year over year

Would someone more skilled be able to help me with it? The output result should be the same.

```
with metric_table as (
  select date'2022-09-08' as date, 'iOs'     as platform, 100 as amount union all
  select date'2022-09-08' as date, 'Android' as platform, 105 as amount union all
  select date'2022-09-07' as date, 'iOs'     as platform, 99  as amount union all
  select date'2022-09-07' as date, 'Android' as platform, 86  as amount union all
  select date'2022-09-01' as date, 'iOs'     as platform, 98  as amount union all
  select date'2022-09-01' as date, 'Android' as platform, 88  as amount union all
  select date'2022-08-08' as date, 'iOs'     as platform, 105 as amount union all
  select date'2022-08-08' as date, 'Android' as platform, 106 as amount union all
  select date'2022-06-08' as date, 'iOs'     as platform, 88  as amount union all
  select date'2022-06-08' as date, 'Android' as platform, 85  as amount union all
  select date'2021-09-08' as date, 'iOs'     as platform, 84  as amount union all
  select date'2021-09-08' as date, 'Android' as platform, 83  as amount
)
, metric_by_platform_daily as (
  select
    date,
    platform,
    amount,

    --Add last periods dates
    date_sub(date, interval 1 day)     as last_day_date,
    date_sub(date, interval 1 week)    as last_week_date,
    date_sub(date, interval 1 month)   as last_month_date,
    date_sub(date, interval 1 quarter) as last_quarter_date,
    date_sub(date, interval 1 year)    as last_year_date
  from
    metric_table
)
select
  --Add Current Period calculations
  mpd.date,
  mpd.platform,
  mpd.amount    as amount_current,

  --Add Period-Over-Period calculations
  dod.amount    as amount_last_day,
  wow.amount    as amount_last_week,
  mom.amount    as amount_last_month,
  qoq.amount    as amount_last_quarter,
  yoy.amount    as amount_last_year
from
  metric_by_platform_daily         as mpd
left join metric_by_platform_daily as dod
  on dod.date = mpd.last_day_date
  and dod.platform = mpd.platform
left join metric_by_platform_daily as wow
  on wow.date = mpd.last_week_date
  and wow.platform = mpd.platform
left join metric_by_platform_daily as mom
  on mom.date = mpd.last_month_date
  and mom.platform = mpd.platform
left join metric_by_platform_daily as qoq
  on qoq.date = mpd.last_quarter_date
  and qoq.platform = mpd.platform
left join metric_by_platform_daily as yoy
  on yoy.date = mpd.last_year_date
  and yoy.platform = mpd.platform
```

Comment: `sum(mpd.amount) over (partition by  mpd.platform order by unix_date(mpd.date) range between 1 preceding and 1 preceding ) as Day_over_days,`   Each `platform` is taken separately. We get the date as a number with `unix_date` and look for the day before: `1 preceding` . For a week, it is  `7 preceding`  For month : `order by extract(year from mpd.date)*12+extract(month from mpd.date) between 1 preceding and 1 preceding`. I do not have time to write it as a nice answer. So please do the other cases and post an answer yourself.